# VB read line by value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hello everyone I'm trying to read line the line

```
Dim line as integer = 0
read= io.file ("local\teste.txt")
line =read.lines()
read.readlines(lines)
```

Comment: I do struggle to understand your question a little here, sorry.  My question, why not just read all lines into a collection, then do what ever processing you need on that collection.  Next question, is there any sort of delimiting in the file your processing, does each single line represent a single record?

Comment: @Rio Hursey not my idea is just to save line the line of a file in the hastings variable with some pause because when I use readline() it reads but not the next line and when I use while of the loop it replaces the values too fast and ends up reading only the last line.

Comment: Please turn Option Strict On for this project and all your projects. You declared `lines` as an `Integer` and `objReader As String` What could it possibly mean for an `Integer` to be greater than a `String`?

Comment: What do you save in your 'teste.txt' file?

Comment: @XingyuZhao  three lines only, but I'll put more soon